# MySQL query not matching due to punctuation

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a query in which I am trying to match the results from a query on one table to the results of a query on another table.  The problem I am having is that the results from the first table may sometimes contain punctuation that causes it not to match the other table results, even though ideally it would.

For example, the returned value from table 1 might be "Acme, Inc.", whereas on the second table it is shown as "acme inc".  Is there a way to, in a way, force these to match?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: with a fulltext index, yes. with a `where foo='acme.inc'` or `where foo like 'acme.inc'`, no, not without major mangling of the terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could either use a [regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) or use wildcard matching.

so you could use:

```
select * from tablename where companyname LIKE '%acme%'
```

this will match anything that has 'acme' in it, the % means anything before/after.

just an extra thought that might be simpler than using regex, it would be an easy job to replace any `,` with a `%`, then use that as a search string. It'll then wildcard that char.

```
$searchstring = str_replace(',', '%', $originalstring);

$qry = "select * from tablename where companyname LIKE '%$searchstring%"'
```

**update**

if you want to use regex, just split your search string into parts on characters, then construct a pattern from that.  (this will split on punctuation and get rid of any spaces)

```
preg_match("/(.*)\p{P}(.*)/", str_replace(' ', '', $searchstring), $output_array);
```

this will give you an array with 3 parts, the whole string, and the split 'bits'.  then just iterate over them and construct a mysql friendly string.  (we want to skip the first, hense `$key` starting at 1)

```
$pattern = '';
for($key = 1; $key < count($output_array); $key++) {
    $pattern .= $output_array[$key] . '.*';
}

$qry = "select * from database where companyname REGEXP '$pattern'";
```

heres a [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/eegq-ccku)

Comment: I would think that regex is the way to go, but if I'm receiving the results from the first table, how do I use that to dynamically create the regex, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE function to replace dots.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE REPLACE(some_col, ".", "") LIKE "%acme%";

SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(some_col, ".", ""), ",", "") = "acme inc";
```

I don't know if replace function accepts regex to use only 1 replace

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing the punctuation . . . if you *know* that the strings are otherwise similar.  For instance:

```
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.name = replace(replace(t2.name, '.', ''), ',', '')
```

You might have to add more `replace()` calls.  Another method is to use wildcard searching, in the other direction:

```
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.name like concat('%', replace(t1.name, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

Of course, this would match "Acme inc" and "Acme Amalgamated Foo & Bar Co., Inc.".  However, in my experience, the difference between names in different tables is more than just punctuation.